# Why can't I join my friend's game and vice versa?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I are playing Minecraft PE, and we're trying to join each other's game. We're both on the same Wifi, and both our local server multiplayers are on.

Our names won't come up for either of us trying to join the other's game, but the other day we were joined fine, it doesn't make any sense.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: First, only one of you have multiplayer on, and then the second person should see it on the game list screen. If not, wait a while. Verify that you are actually connected to the same wifi, some modern routers now have multiple SSIDs and being on separate ones may not always work especially if you are using (either or both) the 'guest' mode on a router which blocks inter device communication.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you both have the same version like if one of you has the beta and the other doesn't, you can't play together.